# How to read this line after "and"

Tags: compounds, compound-complex

I was reading a book and read a sentence which is

> Vyasa draws attention to the dangers of lust and blind obedience to the father when Shantanu agrees to the conditions laid down by Ganga.

Does *and* here mean that dangers of lust as well as dangers of blind obedience to the father? Or are they different terms like

1. Dangers of lust  2. Blind obedience to the father.

And dangers have nothing to do with second term.

Comment: This is an ambiguous sentence. You need to provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read this in context to understand the intended meaning.  There are at least three interpretations

> Vyasa draws attention to (1 the dangers of lust) and (2 blind obedience to the father).

> Vyasa draws attention to the dangers of (1 lust) and (2 [the dangers of] blind obedience to the father).

> Vyasa draws attention to the dangers of (1 lust [to the father]) and (2 [the dangers of] blind obedience to the father).

Of these, only one fits the context: the middle one.  I'm basing this partly on grammar (we don't use "lust to someone") partly on common sense (why would he draw attention to blind obedience if not to warn against the dangers of blind obedience), and partly on my knowledge of Mahabharata (Shantanu's lust for the fisherman's daughter and the promises made by his son to renounce his claim to the throne are a cause ultimately of the Mahabharata war)

Comment: Actually , Shantanu had lust for fisherman's daughter along with that he had also made a promise to his father to marry Ganga( Fisherman's daughter). And in this book it has been mentioned many times that children in pre Vedic times were obedient to their father and that is why Traditions are more important in Indian culture because the elders rule the society.

Comment: In my understanding I feel like your first sentence is more accurate.